# Spring Boot2 functional endpoint WebFluxTest is not matching PUT-with-ID and DELETE-for-id ({id}) URLs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-boot-test

I am working on a Spring boot2 application which has been developed with functional endpoints. The routers are attached with some filters (implementation of `HandlerFilterFunction<ServerResponse, ServerResponse>`). I am trying to test the fliters for which I am stuck and asking this question.

Frameworks used

- Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE
- TestNG

**Filter which I am trying to test**

```
public class ResourceParsingFilter implements HandlerFilterFunction<ServerResponse, ServerResponse> {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Mono<ServerResponse> filter(ServerRequest request, HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> next) {
        final HttpMethod httpMethod = request.method();
        final String requestPath = request.path();

        // Collect the resource id and type from path
        final ResourceDetail resourceDetail = WebUtilsFunctions.FN_GET_RESOURCE_DETAIL_FROM_PATH.apply(requestPath);

        switch (httpMethod) {
        case GET:
            if (!request.queryParam("q").isPresent() && StringUtils.isBlank(resourceDetail.getResourceId())) {
                return Mono.error(
                        new AppException(Exceptions.APP_400002.exceptionCode(), 
                                WebUtilsFunctions.FN_FORMAT_STRING.apply(Exceptions.APP_400002.exceptionMessage(), new String[] {httpMethod.name()})));
            }
            break;
        case PUT:
        case DELETE:
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(resourceDetail.getResourceId())) {
                return Mono.error(
                        new AppException(Exceptions.APP_400002.exceptionCode(), 
                                WebUtilsFunctions.FN_FORMAT_STRING.apply(Exceptions.APP_400002.exceptionMessage(), new String[] {httpMethod.name()})));
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        // Store resourceDetail in request
        request.attributes().put("RESOURCE_DETAIL", resourceDetail);

        return next.handle(request);
    }

}
```

**Mock app config to test the filter**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class MockAppConfig {
    @Bean
    public ResourceParsingFilter resourceParsingFilterBean() {
        return new ResourceParsingFilter();
    }

    @Bean // This is my own custom exception handler implementation
    public GlobalExceptionHandler globalExceptionHandler(final ApplicationContext applicationContext,
            final ServerCodecConfigurer serverCodecConfigurer) {
        return new GlobalExceptionHandler(applicationContext, serverCodecConfigurer);
    }
}
```

**Mock router config** (I created this class separately as per suggestion from Spring Boot team in their gitter channel (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6602)

```
@Configuration
public class MockResourceParsingRouterConfig {
    @Autowired
    private ResourceParsingFilter resourceParsingFilter;

    @Bean("resourceParsingFilterRoutes")
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> resourceParsingFilterRoutes() {
        // Dummy route configuration for testing ResourceParsingFilter
        return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("/resourceParsing/{id}"), req -> ServerResponse.ok().build())
                .andRoute(RequestPredicates.PUT("/resourceParsing/{id}"), req -> ServerResponse.ok().build())
                .andRoute(RequestPredicates.DELETE("/resourceParsing/{id}"), req -> ServerResponse.ok().build())
                .andRoute(RequestPredicates.GET("/resourceParsing/"), req -> ServerResponse.ok().build()) // GET Search URL
                .filter(resourceParsingFilter);
    }
}
```

**The test class**

```
@Test(groups = "resourceParsingFilterTests")
@WebFluxTest
@Import({MockAppConfig.class, MockResourceParsingRouterConfig.class})
public class ResourceParsingFilterTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

//  ====== Passing tests
    @Test
    public void get_withoutId() {
        webTestClient.get().uri("/resourceParsing/")
            .exchange() // Fire http request
            .expectStatus() // Assert on HTTP Status
            .isBadRequest()
            ;
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"get_withoutId"})
    public void get_withoutId_searchQueryParamPresent() {
        webTestClient.get().uri("/resourceParsing/?q=id:345")
            .exchange() // Fire http request
            .expectStatus() // Assert on HTTP Status
            .isOk()
            ;
    }

    // ====== Failing tests
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"get_withoutId_searchQueryParamPresent"})
    public void put_withoutId() {
        webTestClient.put().uri("/resourceParsing/")
            .exchange() // Fire http request
            .expectStatus() // Assert on HTTP Status
            .isBadRequest()
            ;
    }
}
```

Th test `put_withoutId` is failing because (mock) server is throwing `404` instead of expected `400`.

Please check GitHub repo https://github.com/nnanda2016/router-fn-demo for complete code (if you prefer) which is a demo app in the same line as my real application (I cannot share real code because of client confidentiality compliance).

Can someone give me some pointers on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The `@WebFluxTest` annotation does not support the testing of `RouterFunction`, but only WebFlux annotated controllers.

`@WebFluxTest` and `@WebMvcTest` are about testing single annotated Controllers as web components without the complete web infrastructure. `RouterFunction` often depend on multiple handlers to define the actual function - so we can't consistently test a single handler without having hard assumptions about the routing or asking developers to contrive their architecture to have multiple `RouterFunction` beans.

This will be better documented [once this Spring Boot issue is resolved](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10683).

In the meantime, you should probably use a `@SpringBootTest` for that; if you don't ask for a specific port, this integration will configure the complete web stack but won't start any server.